# checking the transferFrom method from the Openzeppelin vanilla ERC20

Tags: contract-development

```
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
```

why transfer first and then check that msgSender is allowed to transfer? Should we not first check that and then transfer in order to save time and gas?

Comment: The execution order is important when you are interacting with another contract. In this case these functions only update the internal state, and since the end result is consistent the order is fine.

Comment: right but why bother updating the internal state in the first line to discover at the second line that actually you should not have: surely it is more work (so more gas) and also does not help readability

Comment: As it is implemented each internal function update separate parts of the state: _transfer updates users' balances and _approve updates users' approvals, so they can be switched around and the end result will be the same. Although since _transfer calls `_beforeTokenTransfer` the order is important, the hook will be called before any modification to the state.

Comment: I guess my question follows from me not having a good model of the operational semantics of solidity. What I would have written, would be the following: 1) test then update allowances, 2) update _balances. Here it is done in the opposite order, which means that in the case ```_allowances[sender][_msgSender]``` fails 1) one also has to undo the transfer, 2) ```sender``` paid avoidable gas.

Comment: I take your point about the ```_beforeTokenTransfer``` call being made by ```_transfer``` and therefore the need to call ```_transfer``` first; but then: 1) either I test allowances in that prefix, 2) or not. If not my point stands, If I do, then it is worse, because now even legitimate calls will pay calling ```_allowances``` twice. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: You should ask OpenZeppelin developers directly they usually hang around forum.openzeppelin.com, or leave a comment in their github repo.

Comment: So i got a really good answer https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/in-erc20-tranferfrom-why-transfer-before-checking-allowance/5312